# Populating CGridView one to many relation

Tags: yii

In my project one of the model named **types** having multiple relation to other models the criteria with part is giving below its like

```
$criteria->with = array(
            'category',
            'subCategory',
            'accountsSupplierPriceDetails' => array(
                'with' => 'serviceLevel'
            )
        );
```

the relationship goes like

- types - category - relation(1-1)
- types - subcategory - relation(1-1)
- types - accountsSupplierPriceDetails - relation(1-1)
- accountsSupplierPriceDetails - serviceLevel - relation(1-n)

my problem is how to display the names from each table in a grid. the result of (1-n) should be displayed in a dropdownbox. when i try to access the data from column it shows the error ***Trying to get property of non-object*** ($data->accountsSupplierPriceDetails->serviceLevel ->name). can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: soory its actually my problem. sorry.. if found the issue and solved it.. thanks

Comment: I'd love to see your answer, if you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: have a similar problem, can u put up the solution?

Comment: i will do what i do is the multiple entry for one entry is populated on a drop down list on the grid. right now i dont have the code. but i will post it here on monday. i am out from home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my view i create a cgridview with 5 rows in which one row data is populated using dropdownlist.

```
    <div style="width:700px; height:auto;">
        <?php
        $widget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'response-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $pickdataset->pickCategorylistingForMain(),
            'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/media/css/gridview.css',
            'summaryText' => '',
            'ajaxUpdate' => 'response-grid',
            'enablePagination' => true,
            'pager' => array(
                'class' => 'LinkPager',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'header' => false,
                'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
                'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'id',
                    'header' => '#',
                    'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'name' => 'categoryExt',
                    'header' => 'Category',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'header' => 'Sub Category',
                    'value' => '$data->subCategory->name',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'name' => 'locationExt',
                    'header' => 'Location',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'header' => 'Name',
                    'value' => 'CHtml::dropDownList($data->corporate_id."-".$data->category_id."-".$data->sub_category_id."-".$data->location_id,"",popDropBox($data->masterCategoryServiceLevels), array("class" => "listbox"), array("empty" => "Select a Location"))',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'header' => 'Pick',
                    'value' => 'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/media/images/edit_icon.png",$data->corporate_id."-".$data->category_id."-".$data->sub_category_id."-".$data->location_id,array("title" => "Select this Combination"))',
                ),
            ),));

        function popDropBox($data)
        {
            $list = array();
            foreach ($data as $row)
            {
                $list[$row->serviceLevel->id] = $row->serviceLevel->name;
            }
            return $list;
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

**the relation in model is:**

```
'masterCategoryServiceLevels' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MasterCategoryServiceLevel', 'category_template_id'),
'corporate' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AccountsCorporate', 'corporate_id'),
'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MasterCategory', 'category_id'),
'subCategory' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MasterCategory', 'sub_category_id'),
'location' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MasterLocation', 'location_id'),
```

**the row is**

```
array(
'type' => 'raw',

'header' => 'Name',

'value' => 'CHtml::dropDownList($data->corporate_id."-".$data->category_id."-".$data->sub_category_id."-".$data->location_id,"",popDropBox($data->masterCategoryServiceLevels), array("class" => "listbox"), array("empty" => "Select a Location"))',
                    ),
```

**and i use a function to create dropdown data is**

```
function popDropBox($data)
            {
                $list = array();
                foreach ($data as $row)
                {
                    $list[$row->serviceLevel->id] = $row->serviceLevel->name;
                }
                return $list;
            }
```

please comment if you have any doubt. i am free to share... have a nice day SO friends... wishes and prayers.

Comment: @DroidUser i hope this answer helped you.

Comment: is it possible within the Gridview? @Jaison Justus